# How many local work-items are in a single work-group in case of a 2 work dimensions

Tags: opencl

If I have 2 work dimensions and set `local_work_size` of [clEnqueueNDRangeKernel](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.html) to, say, `{4, 4}`, would a single work-group consist of 4*4=16 local work-items or just 4 of them?

There is an image that describes 1 dimension case, in which each work-group contains all local work-items of the only dimension that is there, but I don't know how that expands to 2 dimension case, thus the question.

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [fixstars.com](https://www.fixstars.com/images/openclbook/dtp_462724_USER_CONTENT_0_html_3bb3f126.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct with your assumption that a local work-size with `{4, 4}` will yield 16 work-items per work-group. [Here](https://jorudolph.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/opencl-work-item-ids-globalgrouplocal/)  is an image showing this.

Additional info (in case you need it):
The choice of dimension is strongly dependent on your actual problem, but also on memory access patterns and optimiziation potential. 
However most problems can be solved using 1-dimensional work-sizes (even when working with 2-dimensional data), especially if there is no involvement of neighboring values when processing elements.

Comment: Also, if you do specify a local work group size, your global work size must be an integer multiple of it (in OpenCL 1.x). So if your local work group size is {4, 4} then global work size could be (for example) {4, 4}, or {4, 40}, or {256, 4} but not {6, 10}.

Comment: Yes, because the number of work-groups is implied from global and local work-group sizes and it should be an integer.